# how to set scrolling longlistselector same as people application in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am developing application using longlistselector in windows phone 7.
but I am struggle with scrolling when I scrolling longlistselector it is scrolling total view but need only scrolling first Iteamgroup scrolling up to come second groupitem coming to top same process (for example people hub application in windows phone 7 and office application in windows 
phone 7).

screens [image]

any one can you help to me ....

Thanks,
Ram

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the longlistselector from the Windows Phone Toolkit, then this is not possible.

However, if you're using the built in longlistselector for Windows Phone 8 it's enabled by default

Comment: but people hub application working in windows phone 7 also with same scrolling .

Comment: Technically this is possible, but not with the standard control of the toolkit. You'd have to implement a new control yourself. Alternatively you could download the source of the toolkit from codeplex and implement this behavior

Comment: can you give any idea or any sample for this please ?

Comment: I suggest you download the source code and try to implement this yourself. If you run into problems, I'll be glad to help you out.